# Is it possible to form a bijection from N to Z if 0 is not an element of N?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ for this assignment, which isn't terribly difficult however 0 is not included in $\mathbb{N}$ as defined by this book i'm working in... which mmakes it a little difficult, I have nothing to map to zero.

Comment: If $f$ is a bijection $\mathbb N_0\to\mathbb Z$, then what is $g(x)=f(x-1)$, defined on $\mathbb N_+$?

Comment: Also, I think this question is not properly related to real analysis, right?

Comment: @awllower what would be a question properly related to real analysis?

Comment: I mean I don't see how this question is related to "Theoretical foundations of calculus: limits, convergence of sequences, construction of the real numbers, least upper bound property, and related analysis topics such as continuity, differentiation, integration through the fundamental theorem of calculus." In fact, I think this is a purely set-theoretical question. Of course it is only a personal opinion.

Comment: it's just the beginning of the class, so it's probably to get us familiar with working with this stuff before jumping in to that.

Comment: I see. But notice that the content of a class of real analysis is not limited to real analysis: some set-theoretical foundations also pertain to such a class. In any case, it is not too big a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:
$$f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb N$$
$$n\rightarrow\begin{cases}2n&n\gt0\\-2n+1&n\le0\end{cases}.$$
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is the inverse map, whose bijectivity is not difficult to show.

Comment: this is beautiful, thanks a lot.

Comment: NP; it is my pleasure.

Comment: i hope that one day immm as smart as you so i can help people too.

Comment: You are helping people by asking this question right here. Other people might benefit from your questions in effect. :D

Comment: that's a good point!